# asset_path or asset_url for refrencing the file in sigma.js on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sigma.js

I have some javascrips and my aims is  to pars a file.

my javascriptfiles are located in

```
.../app/assets/javascripts/
```

I have uploaded the file (to be parsed)in

```
.../app/assets/models/fileA.gexf
```

my view looks like the following :

```
<% content_for :header do %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "sigma.min", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "sigma.parseGexf", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<% end %>
```

.

.

.

```
      sigInst.parseGexf(asset_path("models/fileA.gexf"));
```

I do not get the result that I want, is it asset_path   thats problematic?

Comment: I'm not sure this is your problem, but I notice you say fileA.gexf is in assets/models/, while your call to asset_path is using gexf/.

Comment: @AndrewLorente That was a type sorry. No this is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

You might need to explicitly add additional js files to be precompiled in config/application.rb:

`config.assets.precompile += %w(sigma.min)`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: I added this line and precompiled but no java files has been added to public

Comment: So I added this `    config.assets.precompile += %w(sigma.parseGexf.js sigma.min.js)` and now these files are added to public

Comment: still the problem exist

Comment: Did you restart your server after adding that line to the config? You shouldn't need to run any asset precompile tasks if you're running in development mode so there shouldn't be any js in your public folder - only in app/assets/javascripts and Rails will do the rest.

Comment: I am in production environment